# Local Storage, Cannot read property 'platformId' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hi I am developing an ionic-angular pwa and recently I decided to use local storage to store authentication info.
I followed the steps according to [Ionic Storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage)

But in the end I get the following error:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'platformId' of undefined
at provideStorage (ionic-storage-angular.js:49)
at _callFactory (core.js:23707)
at _createProviderInstance (core.js:23663)
```

The only way I could solve the error is to add Storage to the Providers list in app.module.ts; But according to recent release I should not.
I would be thankful if you can tell my what is wrong.

My packages versions are:

"@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",

"@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",

"@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this error by adding Storage to the Providers list in app.module.ts. However you need to import the Storage package from @ionic/storage-angular rather than @ionic/storage. I know that the recent release currently says not to do this, but i was unable to run my application with this entry.

Try this in your app.module.ts

```js
import { IonicStorageModule,Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    Storage
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the only way it worked for me.

Comment: For ionic 5, import is import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';